# Android RAM page size?

Tags: java, android, linux

I would like to optimize the reading of an InputStream, then I thought it would be good to have a byte[] buffer with the size of a RAM page.

Is there a method (possibly a static one) to know its size?

### EDIT:

Finally I succeeded using NDK and JNI, I wrote the following code in C:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <unistd.h>

jlong Java_it_masmil_tests_TestsActivity_pageSize(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
    return sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
}
```

where:

- it.masmil.tests is the package name
- TestsActivity is the class name
- pageSize is the method name
- env and javaThis are two mandatory parameters (usefull in some occasions)

I compiled that file with NDK, and then I wrote the following code in Java:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("clibrary");
}
private native long pageSize();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    long page = pageSize();
}
```

where:

- clibrary is the name of the library I created with NDK
- pageSize is the name of the method as declared in the C file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page size is defined by Linux (kernel) and you can get it via JNI by calling libc ([bionic](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/sys/sysconf.h#L77))'s `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. Since Android runs on Linux and mostly on ARM systems, you can assume 4k page sizes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
long sz = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

However you can't really get this kind of alignment from Java/C easily. Meaning even if you ask for a 4k block, no one guarantees that will be 4k aligned.

In case you need a 4k aligned block on Linux, you should use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) which is guaranteed to be page size aligned.

Comment: I've never used it, I tried it but I cannot understand how to let it work... (trying this link http://patriot.net/~tvalesky/jninative.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can generally assume that the page size is 4KB or larger (MMU's that can handle smaller page sizes are practically extinct). Also, if you have no method to align the buffer to an exact page boundary, it will very likely still span two pages.

Lastly, all that effort is completely wasted - if the MMU suffers one or two page misses will be overshadowed by many orders of magnitude by the actual I/O cost. Its even unlikely that you even can recover the added initialization cost, not to mention all the time you spent on implementing it.

You made a perfect example of overzealous optimization effort, you could have spend all that time for a much bigger return (for example) if you just profiled your app and shaved of one or two cycles in the method called most often.

Comment: Mine is not overzealous, I'm realizing a library which may be used for memory operations in Android applications, then I needed to know how to have that information. Furthermore I used this example to learn how to use NDK. How to use that information is the job of the ones which will use this library, my purpose was just to have that value, not to use it...

Comment: I was answering to your questions explicitly stated intent: "I would like to optimize the reading of an InputStream". "A library which may be used for memory operations" doesn't automatically qualify the effort as *reasonable* either, read my entire answer again - you have basically no practicable way of satisfying all the conditions to take advantage of your knowledge about the page size. And even if you could, the payoff wouldn't justify the amount of work that went into it of. I look strictly look at cost vs return, not using an abstract rationalization to convince myself its worth it.

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to believe that adding JNI etc will really repay the cost. Just use 4096 or 8192 like everybody else.